# Clock synchronization

Tags: networking, time, synchronization, clock

I have 2 computers running windows 7.
There are simply networked via LAN cable. One is Master and the other Slave. No Internet connection is available.
WHAT I NEED TO DO:
Each time both windows logged in and connected via LAN to each other, the Slave one sets its clock according to the Master's clock without third party user interference. How to implement this scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Having a LAN connection you can setup a synchronized clock among your machines using [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). It is a protocol which works with great classifiers to keep count of the clock.

Here's a small client that might help you to keep up with the clocks of a few computers running windows, [NetTime](http://www.timesynctool.com/).